# How can feature structures be applied to text summarization?

Tags: natural-language-processing, computational-linguistics

I'm looking for innovative ways to create text summaries and I was
wondering whether [feature structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_structure) can be used for such a task.

Is it possible to create subsume and unification methods that
allow one to model text summary tasks using feature structures?

Comment: @RickyDemer Once again, please do not add manual spacing and line breaks. They might look good on your screen, but they're completely off for other people who use a different font size, who use the mobile site, who use the Android/iOS application, etc.

Comment: @Gilles: Regarding line breaks, I had forgotten where I was. Regarding manual spacing, are [zero-width spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) actually problematic?

Comment: @RickyDemer I don't think zero-width spaces are problematic. But when you add horizontal space to get the line breaks the way you want (which you often do in comments), that usually breaks after a few minutes when the width of the timestamp changes, in addition to looking wrong in different interfaces.